# Can I retrieve a attribute value from a parent element in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, react-props

[image]

When I click on a specific button I want to capture the {country} prop associated with it.
I tired the following

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


// ====================================================================[SEARCH-BAR]=======================================================
// search component
const SearchBar = (props) => {
    // console.log(props);
    const { searchString, searchOnChangeEventHandler } = props
    return (
        <>
            <form>
                <label>Search </label>
                <input type='text' placeholder='type to search...' value={searchString} onChange={searchOnChangeEventHandler} />
            </form>
        </>
    )
}

// ================================================================[COUNTRY_CARD]==========================================================
// countryCard component
const CountryCard = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    return (
        <div>
            <p>countryName</p>
            <p>capital</p>
            <p>population</p>
            <p>languages</p>
            <ul>
                <li>item</li>
                <li>item</li>
            </ul>
            <p>image flag</p>
        </div>
    )
}


// ===================================================================[DISPLAY]===========================================================
// display component
const Display = (props) => {
    const [showCountryCard, setShowCountryCard] = useState(false)
    const [thisCountry, setThisCountry] = useState({})
    // console.log(props);
    const { countries, searchString } = props
    // console.log(countries);
    // eslint-disable-next-line eqeqeq

    // searchString empty
    if (searchString == false) {
        return (
            <>
                <div>
                    <span>Type in SearchBar for a country...</span>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }

    // to count number of matches
    const filteredResultsCount = countries.filter(country => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())).length
    // function to filterCountries
    const filteredResults = (searchString, countries) => countries.filter(country => {
        return country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())
    })

    // RENDER CONDITIONS
    // searchString return <= 10 matches && >1 match
    // event handler for show-btn
    const showCardEventHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.parentElement);
        setShowCountryCard(!showCountryCard)
    }
    if (filteredResultsCount <= 10 && filteredResultsCount > 1) {
        return (
            <>
                <ul>
                    {
                        filteredResults(searchString, countries).map(country =>
                            <li
                                key={country.numericCode}
                                country={country}
                            >
                                <span>{country.name}</span>
                                <button
                                    value={showCountryCard}
                                    onClick={showCardEventHandler}
                                >show</button>
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
                {
                    showCountryCard ? <p>show country card</p> : null
                }
            </>
        )
    }
    // searchString returns >10 matches
    if (filteredResultsCount > 10) {
        return (
            <span>{filteredResultsCount} matches!, please refine your search...</span>
        )
    }
    // searchString returns ===1 match
    if (filteredResultsCount === 1) {
        return (
            <>
                {
                    filteredResults(searchString, countries).map(country => <CountryCard key={country.numericCode} country={country} />)
                }
            </>

        )
    }
    // invalid searchString
    if (filteredResultsCount === 0) {
        return (
            <span><strong>{filteredResultsCount} matches!</strong> please refine your search...</span>
        )
    }
}

// ===================================================================[APP]==============================================================
// app component
const App = () => {
    // to store countries
    const [countries, setCountries] = useState([])

    // to fetch data from 
    const url = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all'
    useEffect(() => {
        // console.log('effect');
        axios
            .get(url)
            .then(response => {
                // console.log('promise fulfilled');
                const countries = response.data
                // array of objects
                setCountries(countries)
            })
    }, [])
    // console.log('countries', countries.length);
    // console.log(countries);

    // to store search string
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState('')
    // event handler search input
    const searchOnChangeEventHandler = (event) => setSearchString(event.target.value)

    return (
        <>
            <h1>Countries Data</h1>
            <SearchBar searchString={searchString} searchOnChangeEventHandler={searchOnChangeEventHandler} />
            <br />
            <Display countries={countries} searchString={searchString} />
        </>
    )
}

export default App
```

Please take a look at `<Display/>` component and in particular I'm trying to work on this part

```js
    const showCardEventHandler = (event) => {
        console.log(event.target.parentElement);
        setShowCountryCard(!showCountryCard)
    }
    if (filteredResultsCount <= 10 && filteredResultsCount > 1) {
        return (
            <>
                <ul>
                    {
                        filteredResults(searchString, countries).map(country =>
                            <li
                                key={country.numericCode}
                                country={country}
                            >
                                <span>{country.name}</span>
                                <button
                                    value={showCountryCard}
                                    onClick={showCardEventHandler}
                                >show</button>
                            </li>
                        )
                    }
                </ul>
                {
                    showCountryCard ? <p>show country card</p> : null
                }
            </>
        )
    }
```

I want to be able to render a list of countries if they are more than 10 and allow a user to click on a specific country, which then will be used to render the `<CountryCard/>` component.
If there is only 1 matching value from search then I will directly display the country card component. The second functionality works.

After the following refactor the first functionality works, but Ima  little confused as to why so I'm adding on to the post. This is the component being rendered and now I'm passing country prop onClick, like so

```js
    if (filteredResultsCount <= 10 && filteredResultsCount > 1) {
        return (
            <>
                <ul>
                    {filteredResults(searchString, countries).map((country) => (
                        <li key={country.numericCode} country={country}>
                            <span>{country.name}</span>
                            <button
                                value={showCountryCard}
                                onClick={() => toggleCardEventHandler(country)}>
                                {showCountryCard ? 'hide' : 'show'}
                            </button>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
                {showCountryCard ? <CountryCard country={country} /> : null}
            </>
        );
    }
```

The event handler is as follows

```js
    const toggleCardEventHandler = (country) => {
        // console.log(country);
        setShowCountryCard(!showCountryCard);
        setCountry(country)
    };
```

This works properly.
My question is, when I change the eventHandler `onClick={toggleCardEventHandler(country)}` it breaks, but shouldnt it be accessible through closure?

Also, if I change the code to this

```js
onClick={() => {
    toggleCardEventHandler()
    setCountry(country)
}}
```

The code works the way I want but which is a better way to pass the value to the `toggleCardEventHandler()` and set the country there or to do it like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it you want to pass the `country.name` to your showCardEventHandler.
Update `showCardEventHandler` so it takes the event and the country name:

```
const showCardEventHandler = (event, countryName) => {
  console.log(countryName);
  setShowCountryCard(!showCountryCard)
}
```

Now pass the countryname to the function:

```
<li
  key={country.numericCode}
  country={country}
>
 <span>{country.name}</span>
 <button
   value={showCountryCard}
   onClick={e => showCardEventHandler(e, country.name)}
 >show</button>
</li>
```

Since you are not using the event in `showCardEventHandler` you can remove it from the signature
`const showCardEventHandler = (countryName) => {}`
and call it with `onClick={() => showCardEventHandler(country.name)}`

Comment: why must I call it like `onClick={() => showCardEventHandler(country.name)}` and it works but this `onClick={showCardEventHandler(country.name)}` does not.. I know this is probably an obvious question but I'm a little confused as to why it works, I know its something to do with closure...

Comment: @utsavojha95 that is in the nature of how arrow functions `() => {}` work. To avoid diving deep in a comment I would suggest you give this a read: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-function-component

I guess a rule of thumb can be, if you want to call a function in your event (onClick) with arguments you can use an arrow function. If you don't need arguments you can pass a *reference* to the function like: `onClick={showCardEventHandler}` notice that there are no parentheses, which is intended.